# Mod_rewrite htaccess question

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How could I take a URL like http://example.com/page.php?2342

And turn it into

http://example.com/page/?2342

or is that not possible?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need mod_rewrite for that. You can use [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#negotiation).

```
Options MultiViews
```

in addition to your other options. You need mod_negotiation enabled in your server.

From the docs:

> The effect of MultiViews is as
>   follows: if the server receives a
>   request for /some/dir/foo, if
>   /some/dir has MultiViews enabled, and
>   /some/dir/foo does not exist, then the
>   server reads the directory looking for
>   files named foo.*, and effectively
>   fakes up a type map which names all
>   those files, assigning them the same
>   media types and content-encodings it
>   would have if the client had asked for
>   one of them by name. It then chooses
>   the best match to the client's
>   requirements.
>
> MultiViews may also apply to searches
>   for the file named by the
>   DirectoryIndex directive, if the
>   server is trying to index a directory.
>   If the configuration files specify
>
> DirectoryIndex index then the server
>   will arbitrate between index.html and
>   index.html3 if both are present. If
>   neither are present, and index.cgi is
>   there, the server will run it.
>
> If one of the files found when reading
>   the directory does not have an
>   extension recognized by mod_mime to
>   designate its Charset, Content-Type,
>   Language, or Encoding, then the result
>   depends on the setting of the
>   MultiViewsMatch directive. This
>   directive determines whether handlers,
>   filters, and other extension types can
>   participate in MultiViews negotiation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the /?2342 necessary, or could you do it like this?

```
RewriteRule page/(\d*) page.php?id=$1
```

Otherwise it would be

```
RewriteRule page/\?(\d*) page.php?id=$1
```

(I think that works, anyhow. I can't test it at the moment.)